# MySQL: Create unique value constraint between two columns in the *same* row

Tags: mysql, constraints, unique

Is it possible to create a MySQL constraint to force a unique value between two columns *in the same row?*

For example:

```
CREATE TABLE Buddies (
  User1 int,
  User2 int,
) Type = InnoDB;
```

How would I disallow...

`INSERT INTO MyTable SET User1 = '5', User2 = '5'` ?

That user would be very lonely otherwise :)

**EDIT:** the point here is that I would like to do this purely in MySQL and not in the application layer, if possible.

Comment: trigger which checks the value before inserting it.

Comment: http://cvuorinen.net/2013/05/validating-data-with-triggers-in-mysql/

Comment: In the question I linked - you would also need your columns to be `NOT NULL` so as to cause the error the trigger's trick relies on.

Answer (score 0):

Hi this code makes two column on a row to be unique:

```
ALTER TABLE 'tableName' ADD UNIQUE( 'column1', 'column2');
```

With the code above, if you insert value to `column1` and `column2` identically, it will not be inserted.
For example:

```
$value1 = 1;
$value2 = 2;
$value3 = 3;
mysql_query("INSERT INTO tableName (column1, column2) VALUES ('$value1', '$value2')"); //This will work.
mysql_query("INSERT INTO tableName (column1, column2) VALUES ('$value1', '$value3')"); //This will work.
mysql_query("INSERT INTO tableName (column1, column2) VALUES ('$value1', '$value2')"); //This WILL NOT work THE SECOND time around because of the unique constraint.
```

Or refer to this code:

```
$value1 = 1;
$value2 = 2;

$resultSet = mysql_query("SELECT column1 FROM tableName WHERE column1 = '$value1'");
$rows = mysql_num_rows($resultSet);

if($rows >= 1){
    echo $value1 . " already exist.";
}
else{
    $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO tableName (column1, column2) VALUES('$value1','$value2')");

    if(){
        echo "Value inserted.";
    }else echo mysql_error();
}
```

The code above checks the value of `$value1` before inserting the two values to determined if `$value1` already exist.

Hope this help you. :-)

Comment: I realize I could do this in the application layer, but I was hoping that it could be done purely in MySQL.

Comment: @KielLabuca . .  The code you mean creates a unique index with two fields.  It allows (5, 5) to be inserted once into the table, but not twice.

Comment: @GordonLinoff -- Exactly Mr. Linoff, that's what I meant about the first bunch of code above.

Comment: In his question, he mentioned two columns in the same table so that is the code I provide, however if he wants only one column then he could still use the same code just with one parameter, like this: `ALTER TABLE 'tableName' ADD UNIQUE( 'column1' );`

Comment: @KielLabuca . . . You are missing the point.  The OP is looking for a check constraint on values in the same row, not across all rows.  MySQL does not execute check constraints.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff: yes, this is correct.  I know I can do constraints on multiple columns across multiple rows.  I want a constraint *between* multiple columns in the *same* row.